# Генерация квадратной таблицы

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый вечер!
У меня есть следующая страница:

```html
<html>
<head> 
<title>крестики нолики</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   function ShowImage(id) 
   {  
    if(document.getElementById("flag").title == "false")
    {
     document.getElementById(id).src="1.png";
     document.getElementById("flag").title = "true";
    }else
    {
     document.getElementById(id).src="2.png";
     document.getElementById("flag").title = "false";
    }
   }   
   function CreateTable(size)
   {
    //Создание таблицы
   }
  </script>
 <style type='text/css'>
 td{
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  padding: 2px;
  }
  table{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 1200px;
  min-height: 100px;
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <FORM
   <b>Введите размер таблицы.</b>
   <BR>
   <INPUT TYPE=Text NAME="Info">
   <INPUT TYPE=BUTTON
   ONCLICK="CreateTable(4)"
   VALUE="Создать">
  </FORM> 
 <div id="flag" title = "false"></div>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td/><img id="i1" onClick="ShowImage(this.id)" src="0.png"></td>
   <td/><img id="i2" onClick="ShowImage(this.id)" src="0.png"></td>
   <td/><img id="i3" onClick="ShowImage(this.id)" src="0.png"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td/><img id="i4" onClick="ShowImage(this.id)" src="0.png"></td>
   <td/><img id="i5" onClick="ShowImage(this.id)" src="0.png"></td>
   <td/><img id="i6" onClick="ShowImage(this.id)" src="0.png"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td/><img id="i7" onClick="ShowImage(this.id)" src="0.png"></td>
   <td/><img id="i8" onClick="ShowImage(this.id)" src="0.png"></td>
   <td/><img id="i9" onClick="ShowImage(this.id)" src="0.png"></td>
  </tr>
 </table> 
</body>
</html>
```

На ней таблица, щелкая по ячейкам которых можно изменить картинку на крестик или нолик.

Как сделать такую же таблицу, с таким же функционалом, но с размером, указанным пользователем? 
С помощью только js и html.

Comment: Точно такую же, с таким же количеством ячеек? Или пользователь количество ячеек указывает?

Comment: А что именно у вас не получилось?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function ShowImage(id) {
 
  if (document.getElementById("flag").title == "false") {
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("style", "background: url(http://anonymousglobal.org/commanderx/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/redX2.png);background-size: 50px 50px;");
    document.getElementById("flag").title = "true";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("style", "background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Classic_alphabet_numbers_0_at_coloring-pages-for-kids-boys-dotcom.svg/220px-Classic_alphabet_numbers_0_at_coloring-pages-for-kids-boys-dotcom.svg.png);background-size: 50px 50px;");
    document.getElementById("flag").title = "false";
  }
}

function CreateTable() {
  document.getElementById("tab").innerHTML = '';
  var size = document.getElementById("size").value;
  if (size > 0 && size < 11) {
    var table = document.getElementById("tab");
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      var row = table.insertRow(i);
      for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(j);
        cell1.setAttribute("id", i+ "" + j)
        cell1.addEventListener("click", function(){                      ShowImage(this.getAttribute('id'))
        })
        
      }
    }
  } else {
    alert("input number between 1 and 10");
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  padding: 2px;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
}
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 1200px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>крестики нолики</title>

</head>

<body>
  <b>Введите размер таблицы.</b>
  <br>
  <INPUT TYPE=Text NAME="Info" id='size' />
  <INPUT TYPE=BUTTON ONCLICK="CreateTable();" VALUE="Создать" />
  <div id="flag" title = "false"></div>
  <table id="tab">

  </table> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!
Но я столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Я хочу добавить свой обработчик событий OnClick на ячейку
'    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) 
    {
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(j);
   cell.innerHTML = "onClick=\"ShowImage(this.id)\"";
   cell.src = "1.png";
    }
'
После этого вся таблица ломается и ничего не показывает, в чем проблема? как правильно указывать обработчик событий?

Comment: @SlavaPodolskiy добавил...